# Error AAPT Android Studio when generate signature

Tags: android, android-studio, aapt

I'm trying to generate a signature apk to publish my app to the play store, but this error appears every time

> Task :app:processReleaseResources FAILED
> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{}],"original":"ERROR:: AAPT: /Users/luisabsg/Desktop/ebookandroid-18_1/codecanyon-24119642-ebook-android-app-online-freepaid-book-paypal-admin-panel/MainFiles/AppCode/E-Books App/E-Books App/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/.anim_abc_popup_enter.xml 2.flat.icloud: error: failed to read file: magic value is 0x696c7062 but AAPT expects 0x54504141.\nerror: failed parsing overlays.\n\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
> ERROR:: AAPT: /Users/luisabsg/Desktop/ebookandroid-18_1/codecanyon-24119642-ebook-android-app-online-freepaid-book-paypal-admin-panel/MainFiles/AppCode/E-Books App/E-Books App/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/.anim_abc_popup_enter.xml 2.flat.icloud: error: failed to read file: magic value is 0x696c7062 but AAPT expects 0x54504141.
> error: failed parsing overlays.

[image]

Someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have `*.icloud` files in your project.

Disable any iCloud synchronisation for the project directory.

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: you can check here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254313/how-to-exclude-a-sub-folder-from-icloud-drive-in-macos-sierra

Comment: I understood now hehehe, ty!! I'll try

Answer (score -1):

I encounter the similar problem on Windows，（magic value is 0x696c7062 but AAPT expects 0x54504141， XXXX.flat）
1.delete cache directory, (.gradle\caches\XXXXX)
2.rebuild

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33229355)